# OAuth 2.0 authorization with my own password

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm developing an application with OAuth 2 feature. But my case is special. I only want to use my own account to login. Let me take the Facebook as an example to explain the flow of my application:

1. User start the application
2. Normally the OAuth will request the user login to his/her own FB account to authorize. But in my application, I want to login to my FB account. Because I know the my own user id and password. Is it a method to login to my account silently?
3. User is able to post message. In this case, they will post to my FB account.

Is this possible? Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 allows for this type of flow, as defined in the so-called Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant. However this flow is less preferred and for backwards compatibility only because it defeats OAuth's primary goal of not having to enter end-user credentials in the client.

FB does not support the ROPC grant so you'll have to go through the regular Authorization Code flow. Once you get a `refresh_token` through that initial flow, you can use that as a long-lived credential to get new access tokens in the same way that you would use the FB username/password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I'm not using FB. I have another thinking. That is I'm using server side OAuth to get the the returned html if the user is not logged in. Then I'll login automatically.

Comment: you can try, but it is a pattern that will easily break on changes and FB (the Authorization Server) may actively try to prevent it

Comment: Yes, you're right. It will be affected if the Authorization Server changes. Do you have any better suggestion? Thanks

Comment: as suggested in the answer, authorization code (once) + refresh token

Comment: But my issue is that I'm going to use my own user name and password instead of users.